# Заменить возрастание цены - снижением

Tags: php

```
<div class="cost animate">
  <div class="num countme" xval="<?=preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $arItem['PREVIEW_TEXT'])?>">
    <?=$arItem['PREVIEW_TEXT']?>
  </div> 
  ???.
</div>
```

Суть в том, что есть блок, где цена возрастает до определенной суммы. А нужно, чтобы она с 999999 рублей снижалась до определенной суммы.

Comment: Что за цена? Где снижалась и почему? Кто ее задает?

Comment: А вы, простите, не можете поменять плюс на минус?

Comment: @VladD, Хотя я тоже ничего не понял из условий, кое-что понятно - ему не нужно обратить число, а снизить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно нужно проверять уровень цены и, если он выше максимума, понижать значение методом простейших арифметических операций:

```
<?php

$fCost = 9999;
$sCost = 9998;
$max = 9999;
$threshold = 7000;

if($fCost >= $max)
 $fCost = $fCost - ($fCost - $threshold);
if($sCost >= $max)
 $sCost = $sCost - ($sCost - $threshold);

print $fCost;
print "\n";
print $sCost;
```

[Живой пример кода](http://codepad.org/KAM7R2Li)

Comment: хороший вариант, я не силён в php. как сделать, чтобы с 999999 цена снизилась до 60000 ?

Comment: @KonstantinD, Маленький совет - если ты даже таких элементарных вещей не знаешь, то начни с изучения основ языка. А снизить - в `$max` лежит максимальное значение (для тебя, видимо, нужно 999999 поставить), в `$threshold` лежит число до которого нужно снизить (в твоём случае 60000).

Comment: вот как после этого обращаться к вам, да, я не знаю основ, для этого я и пришел сюда, чтобы мне помогли, а не начали обсуждать.

Comment: @KonstantinD, Дать дельный совет и смотреть с осуждением - вещи разные. Если кто-то не знает основ, но пытается создать что-то - это верный пинок в сторону изучения. Не пустят же меня за консоль рабочей АЭС, ибо с моими знаниями я им там такую Фукусиму устрою. В лучшем случае буду бегать с нубскими вопросами каждую минуту.
Проще выучить хотя бы основы.

Comment: вопрос был срочный, времени на изучение не было. Я в любом случае благодарен.

Comment: @KonstantinD: Ну вы перед тем как брать задание всё же потренировались бы. Не всегда так просто получится. Так что прислушайтесь к совету Доктора. Мы здесь не понтуемся, мы тоже через такое проходили.